Can someone please explain to me how SOL contract addresses are created? Is the CA random or could tokenizer make CA spell something
……………………………………………
I encountered a SOL address with a word literally spelled in the beginning characters and I want to know if its possible to manipulate this

You can generate your own address using solana-keygen grind, ie:
$ solana-keygen grind --starts-with CA:1
Searching with 20 threads for:
        1 pubkey that starts with 'CA' and ends with ''
Wrote keypair to CAhczHACFFZ9TJnhtpJkCWhXd3m2Gi5AYT1jJpXPNh71.json

And use it to create a token:
$ spl-token create-token CAhczHACFFZ9TJnhtpJkCWhXd3m2Gi5AYT1jJpXPNh71.json

